# Basic Design Question about one to many in a table

Tags: database-design

Sorry for the basic question but I am new to all of this!

Say I have a table named Runs, and each table has

```
Run:
  id (primary_key)
  data (String - path to a data file)
  status
  timestamp
  ... etc etc
```

Another part of the application takes the data and compares it to other runs, so I want a Comparison table.

```
Comparison:
  id (primary_key)
  tag 
  timestamp
  base (foreign_key to run.id)
  reference_file (foreign_key to run.id)
```

But a comparison will have at least one reference, but possibly many reference. I'd need to tag a comparison to one reference differently than a comparison to many, even if they both contain the same reference file.

Is this the correct approach?

Edit: Clarifying a comparison

A comparison will have one base file, and at least one reference file.

In general two comparisons are run:

First - compare current run against previous run
Second - compare current run against previous 10 runs.

Basically, like this:

```
status = compare_files(current, reference_files)
status = compare_files(run_70, [run_69])
status = compare_files(run_70, [run_69, run_68, run_67, run_66, run_65, run_64, run_63, run_62, run_61, run_60])
```

Since both have a different number of reference files, there will be two different results with logs generated.

Eventually I'll care about the logs and status, but for now I want to intelligently map runs with their comparisons. So I can query a run and a comparison table to get all the required info.

Comment: So, you may have more than 1 comparisons between the same "base" and the same "reference" run. Right?

Comment: Generally we run at least 2 comparisons per run, one against the last run, and one against the last 10 runs. I want to be able to create an entry for both, but they're not the same, and will have different results.

Comment: Your comments do not make clear if a "comparison" involves 2 runs only or sometimes more than 2. Can you add some sample data in the question?